# How to append to an existing file in R without overwriting it?

Tags: r

I would like to write to a file and then append it several times in a loop (on a windows machine). After each time I append it, I want to close the connection because **I want the file to sink to a dropbox account so I can open it on other computers, while the code is running, to check the log file's status** (note this condition makes this question different from any question asked on SO about sink, writeLines, write, cat, etc). I've tried

```
#set up writing
  logFile = file("log_file.txt")
  write("This is a log file for ... ", file=logFile, append=FALSE)

for(i in 1:10){
    write(i, file=logFile, append=TRUE)
}
```

I've also tried `sink(file=logFile,append=TRUE); print(i); sink()`; in the loop and also `cat`. Neither option works. The file only displays i=10, the last iteration of the loop. I noticed the following sentence in the documentation for write.

"if TRUE the data x are appended to the connection."

Does the above mean that it won't append to an existing file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following seems to work with cat because it doesn't need a file connection:

```
#set up writing
logFile = "log_file.txt"
cat("This is a log file for ... ", file=logFile, append=FALSE, sep = "\n")

for(i in 1:10){
  cat(i, file=logFile, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")
}
```

The output would look like so it does append each value:

```
This is a log file for ... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Which I think is what you want. If you are on a mac or using linux you can keep track of progress in the file using:

```
tail -f log_file.txt
```

I am not sure how this would work with dropbox however. Can you login to the computer running the code (e.g., on mac or linux)?

Comment: this code appears to append to the file but it doesn't sink with dropbox which might mean the file remains open? Perhaps specifically closing the file after the cat call?

Comment: oh it's working now, that's strange the initial code wasn't but this one was. They looked pretty much the same though. Maybe dropbox just couldn't handle the long loop.

Comment: `for(i in 1:1000000000){
  if(i %% 10000000 ==0) cat(i, file=logFile, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")
}` that's how I finally verified your code works, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

what about explicitly closing the file after every iteration?

```
#set up writing
  file.text <- "log_file.txt"
  logFile = file(file.txt)
  write("This is a log file for ... ", file=logFile, append=FALSE)
  close(logFile)
for(i in 1:10){
    logFile <- file(file.text)
    write(i, file=logFile, append=TRUE)
    close(logFile)
}
```

Comment: this code appears not to append to the file but rather overwrites it.

Comment: @MHH how to avoid overwriting it?